# Submenu in actionbar not working after supportInvalidateOptionsMenu is called

Tags: android

I have an activity that extends the ActionBarActivity that's included in the support package revision 18. I have a menu item that contains a submenu and it works fine when I load up the app. However, if I call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() for some reason the submenu doesn't pop up any more. The related code would be the xml for the menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    myapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_now_playing"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nowplaying"
    android:title="@string/menu_nowplaying"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_station_overflow"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_overflow"
    android:title="@string/more"
    myapp:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_favorite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
            android:title="@string/favorite"/>
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

And then the code to create the menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I should note that this problem occurs on Gingerbread devices but there are no problems on android 4.x. Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: A less-than-ideal solution would be to move that code into onPrepareOptionsMenu(). In case you can't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a work-around (as we had the same issue).  Any menu items that need to be modified later, we put into instance variables, example:

```
private MenuItem stationMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);

    stationMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_station_overflow);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void doStuff(boolean menuVisible) {
    if (stationMenuItem != null) {
        stationMenuItem.setVisible(menuVisible);
    }
}
```

This is NOT an ideal solution, but something that will work till this is fixed.  Changes to menu items SHOULD happen in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` after calling `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: I'll accept it as an answer since this is probably just a bug and there is no real solution or nothing that I'm doing wrong. This is a working workaround. However, I have more problems when I try to add a submenu to a fragment, i.e. if I let the fragment do setHasOptionsMenu(true) and try to add a submenu via the fragment that won't work. That's not a part of my questions though so I'll just accept this.

Comment: Have you tried saving the Menu to an instance variable (during onCreateOptionsMenu) and then add submenu items later?

Answer (score 0):

Do not return `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` because that will always return false. Just return true.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) does not always return false. I assigned at as a variable and debugged and noticed it did in fact always return true. If it would return false, the menu wouldn't show.

Comment: D'oh, sorry to waste your time. It could be a bug in the support package, I suppose. I don't recall ever seeing a sub-menu on Gingerbread, so it may be a rarely used feature and not have been tested adequately. Are you using ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: No problem. I'm using the new ActionBarActivity that google released with the support library, first seen in version r18. It must be a bug, I'm finding no way around this.